# Why Airflow dag logic run time varies from milliseconds?

Tags: python, airflow

I observed, for example, if a dag interval is set to 1 minute, I'd expect the dag logic run time is 60000 milliseconds apart. However, it is actully 60000+-1000 ms.

My question is why.

Thank you.

Comment: Why should the running time stay perfectly constant ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it sounds weird but there're use cases require ms level accuracy like video timecode

Comment: This is not what I am asking. What would make it constant ?

Comment: I need the intervals fully and continuously covers the whole timeline, not scattered leaving milliseconds gap.

Comment: Can't you answer my question ?

Comment: usually if someone cant answer a question it is because the both parties talk past each other. please reformulate the question and try to find a mutual consense about what is asked. i am sure this will help finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is nobody knows. Solution is do not rely on Airflow's internal scheduler's clock if you need millisecond level accuracy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).